# binary operator expected after using if in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I recently starting approaching bash and I am trying to do the following:
search if a word is in a certain file. If it is then write it to another file if not just exit, but I am getting a binary operator excepted in the if statement.
The code is

```
#!bin/bin/bash
var=$1
if [ grep var file1.txt]
then
    echo var >| file2.txt
else
    exit -1
exit 0
```

I am also open to any constructive criticism, bash tips and good practice in bash

FIXED----
I found out that there was something off with my `[]` from the if statement but I managed to us it without, I also learned that you need a `$` if you want to print variables, also exit codes are from 0 to 255
Updated code-----

```
#!bin/bin/bash
var=$1
if [ grep "$var" file1.txt]
then
    echo "$var" >| file2.txt
else
    exit 1
exit 0
```

Comment: Please show some example input, the example contents of `file1.txt` and the corresponding expected contents of `file2.txt`. Read the documentation of bash's ``if` and `[` commands.

Comment: Please post our code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and follow the given suggestions until it works.

Comment: You need to close/terminate your `if` statement with a `fi`.   Also `exit -1` should probably be `exit 1`.

Comment: ```if [ grep var file1.txt]``` - put space after your file name before closing bracket.

Comment: @Saboteur That's not causing the error, nor is it needed for the intended condition. Neither bracket should be there at all.

Comment: The `if` is irrelevant.  You are executing the command `[ grep var file1.txt]`.  The `[` command expects its arguments to conform to a certain pattern.  Since you gave more than 2 arguments, it expected a binary operator.

Comment: @chepner, [] is not "if" syntax, it is separate command "test". So you should use just ```if grep var file1.txt; then```

Comment: Yes, which is why the lack of a space preceding `]` is not the problem; `test` raises the error before even examining all the arguments to see that the expected final argument `]` is missing. As soon as it sees `grep`, it expects the next argument to be a binary operator, which the value of `$var` is not.